# Keeping model state in asp.net mvc when filtering through objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have an app that makes an api call to get a list of Books that show the Title and Author of a book. They can search by author or by title. I want to save the state in between so that they can search within their search rather than a fresh API call each time but I am not sure how with ASP.Net MVC.

I have the following Controller:

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync(string Authors, string BookTitles)
        {
            // code here makes an API call to get a list of book data and deserializes into book objects
                            
                          var bookList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Books[]>(data);

                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(BookTitles))
                                {
                                   // code displays book titles that match 
                                    return View(bookTitles);
                                }

                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Authors))
                                {
                                    // code displays top 10 books that match author name
                                    return View(authors);
                                }

                                return View(bookList);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            return View();
```

I have the following view:

```
@model Book[]
  <div class="text-center">
            <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" method="get">
                <p>
                    <input type="text" name="BookTitles">
                    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
                </p>
            </form>

            <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" method="get">
                <p>
                    <input type="text" name="Authors">
                    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
        <p>
            <div class="text-center">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" type="button" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Refresh Library</a>
            </div>
        </p>
        <div>
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col" style="width: 20%">Title</th>
                        <th scope="col" style="width: 20%">Author</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                @{
                    foreach (var book in @Model)
                    {
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">@book.Title</th>
                                <th scope="row">@book.Author</th>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    }
                }
            </table>
        </div>
```

My problem that I want to solve is that if a user enters some authors first and gets the result filtered by authors, and then wants to search FROM that new list and inputs some words that might match the title, there is a fresh API call and they receive all titles that match their search rather than the ones that match the author from their first search. I want to save the state of the Books that are displayed so that the user can search from them. Does anyone have ideas on how to do this? I know that using cookies/sessions is an option but not sure if it's the right way to go?

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/state-management-in-asp-net-mvc/

Answer (score 0):

You can store `Authors` and `BookTitles` in ViewBag in the Action.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync(string Authors, string BookTitles)
{

    ViewBag.BookTitles= BookTitles;
    ViewBag.Authors= Authors;

    //...
}
```

And display it in the form input

```
<input type="text" name="Authors" value="@ViewBag.Authors">
<input type="text" name="BookTitles" value="@ViewBag.BookTitles">
```

**Update**

```
var bookList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Books[]>(data);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(BookTitles))
{
     booklist = filterBooksByTitle(BookTitles) //fake code, filter based on your codes
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Authors))
{
    booklist = filterBooksByAuthor(Authors)
}

return View(bookList);
```

Comment: Thanks @mj1313 but this refreshes every time because if they submit an Author search the BookTitles is null

Comment: Yeah, it should be null, but when you submit second time with the title, author will still have the value you previously submitted.

Comment: sorry that is what I meant, when I search a second time Author no longer has the value.

Comment: ohh.. you should put the author and title in one form, don't spearate them into two forms.

Comment: no sorry unfortunately I need two separate search boxes for the design requirements. I also need them to return two different outputs e.g. searching authors outputs top 10 and searching titles will output all.

Comment: Yeah, there are still two search boxes, I just put them in one form, beacause  they all target one controller action.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks @mj1313, yes this keeps the values but the list of Books[] is still refreshed by the API call

Comment: Don't return in the if condition, assign the filtered result to the booklist. See my update.